# DES_cblock and Key Recovery

Tags: des, openssl, key-reuse

I'm trying to get my hands on the key that OpenSSL uses for a DES encryption. The key is based off a random number generator with a seed taken as parameter.

The code used is below, provided as part of my assignment. I'd like to get my hands on DES_cblock key both for debugging and to understand how the OpenSSL works. And also to XOR the key back with the encrypted text.

But how do I work with the DES_cblock data type? Is there a way to print a DES_cblock? Can I get the bits so that I can XOR it?

Thanks for any help!

`void encrypt(uint32_t seed, const string& plaintext) {
    DES_cblock iv, key;
    DES_key_schedule schedule;
    srand(seed);
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
      key[i] = (unsigned char)rand();
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
      iv[i] = (unsigned char)rand();
    DES_set_odd_parity(&key);
    DES_set_key_checked(&key, &schedule);
    int fd = open("des.enc", O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(!fd) {
      cout << "Could not open des.enc" << endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    DES_enc_write(fd, plaintext.c_str(), plaintext.size(), &schedule, &iv);
    close(fd);
}`

Comment: See Thomas Pornin's answer to this question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase/29139 Does that help?

Comment: This is a C++ question, not crypto, nor even OpenSSL except to know `DES_cblock` is a typedef for `unsigned char [8]`. Try SO and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370323/printing-an-array-in-c to start. But tell your teacher the error return from `open()` is -1; 0 is a perfectly valid file descriptor and used for STDIN although usually already open and thus not used for a new open. And FYI XORing ciphertext with the same key is useless; whitening with additional key like DESX can help in general, but nothing will save a scheme that seeds random from 32bits as here.

Comment: Hint: the meat of the crypto part of the problem is in`srand(seed);` which gathers (too little) entropy, and the 4 lines that follows which make use of that. One way to tackle the problem is to find and analyses the simple (in comparison to DES) relation between that initial entropy and something that you know from the message, deduce `key[]`, then decipher the message without breaking DES, which is still way too compute-intensive to ask in an assignment.